# Binding of cells in UITableView does not work properly when reused and built with Xcode9

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, realm, mvvmcross, xcode9

I have a list UITableView containing items. Everything is working fine until I reuse cells using
var cell = TableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier, indexPath);

Then the binding on the reused cells for new items does not work. The items in the table view are repeated constantly. The underlying data is loaded properly.

The code also ran fine until I updated Xcode from version 8 to 9. When I go back everything is fine again.
The iOS version does not seem to matter.

I'm using MVVMCross 4.4 for view binding.

Visual Studio For Mac is updated to the latest version.

**Edit:**

Below my code for cell reuse:

```
protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {
            var original = base.RowsInSection(tableView, (nint) 0);

            if (original > 0)
            {
                var cell = TableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier(indexPath, item), indexPath);
                var frame = cell.Frame;
                frame.Width = TableView.Frame.Width;
                cell.Frame = frame;

                if (cell is T)
                    return ApplyForItem ((T)cell, indexPath);
                else
                    return ApplyForItemFallback (cell, indexPath);
            }

            return TableView.DequeueReusableCell(IsLoading ? LoadingCell.Key : NoDataCell.Key, indexPath);
        }
```

But I do not think that this code is buggy. The DequeueReusableCell method returns required cells but those cells aren't bound correctly to my items.

**Edit:**
We found out that if we clone all of the items in the list bound, the problem does not exist. It seems to be an optimization of mmvmcross or xcode.

I forgot to mention that the items bound are Realm items not just POCO's.

Answer (score 0):

```
string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";
string[] TableItems;

public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIdentifier);
        string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
```

I did not have any problems with the above code.Can you provide your code?

If you don't have much data, you can use `UITableViewCell cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);` instead. It cancels the reuse mechanism and adds extra memory.

Comment: I edited my question above. And `var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);` returns null. And also I think there are too many items.

Comment: I cannot provide the whole code. But which one are you interested in?

Comment: the code in  public override UITableViewCell GetCell

Comment: We do not override `UITableViewCell GetCell(...)`. I pasted the code of `UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(...)` above.